# What name is given to an abeam waypoint in the FMS?

Tags: fms, waypoint

In a Flight Management System, what name is given to an abeam waypoint in case of DIR TO?
Is this name format different in Thales and Honeywell FMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Thales Pilot Guide:

> **If ABEAM PTS are desired:
>
>   ABEAM PTS [3R] .......... Confirm/Press**
>   If Option 1 is defaulted, ABEAM PTS is displayed yellow, if not press [3R].
>
> ND shows direct track (dashed yellow), as entered, superimposed on existing ACTIVE F-PLN.
>   *Abeam WPTs are named ABxxxxx, xxxxx representing the first five characters of the relative WPTs.
>
>   Ex: ABADAIB, ABBOKNO, ABDEVRO*

Honeywell FMS is different:

> Abeam Points (ABEAM PTS)
>
> Push -
>
> - creates place bearing distance waypoint on the Direct To leg abeam
>     the bypassed waypoint if the bypassed waypoint was a database
>     airport, navaid, NDB, or waypoint
> - creates latitude/longitude waypoint on the Direct To leg abeam the
>     bypassed waypoint if the bypassed waypoint was a
>     latitude/longitude waypoint

So in the Honeywell FMS the abeam points will use the Place Bearing Distance name or the Lat/Lon name depending on the type of original waypoint.

Comment: @Federico  Looks good.  Thanks for the edit.